# django forms hiding multiplechoice fields

Tags: django, django-forms

In the following how to hide all the fields except where label = 'student',

labels can be student,leader,teacher

```
for role in role_list:
            field_name = self.get_member_field_name(role.id)
            label = role.name  // student,leader,teacher

            self.fields[field_name] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                                                            label=label)
            self.fields[field_name].choices = users_list
            self.fields[field_name].initial = []
```

Answer (score 5):

```
self.fields[field_name] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    required=False, 
    label=label, 
    widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput()
)
```

Answer (score -1):

use HiddenInput widget to hidde fields

if label is not student:

```
self.fields[field_name] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),required=False,label=label)
```

Comment: This will cause a validation error. @spiderlama's answer is correct.

Comment: To clarify since I was a little confused, HiddenInput does not work for multiple inputs like `MultipleChoiceField` or `ModelMultipleChoiceField`. Django provides a separate widget called `MultipleHiddenInput` for this purpose. `HiddenInput` will set the value to the repr of the list of items like `[1, 2]`, which does not work.